# Characters which appeared least

Tags: c, if-statement, for-loop

I find such a function, modified it a bit, but it seems to outputs argumnets which appeared the most, but I tried to make it outputs least appearing character.

```
 void leastOften(int *s) {
        int i, j;
        int min[256] = {0} ;
        int min_count = 1000;
        for (i=0; i<256; i++) {
            if (s[i]) {
                if (s[i] < min_count) {
                    for (j=0; j<256; j++)
                        min[j]=0;
                    min[i]=1;
                    min_count = s[i];
                } // 2nd_if
                else if (s[i] == min_count)
                    min[i]=1;
            } // 1st_if
        } //1st_for
        printf("The least appearing characters are: ");
        for (i=0; i<256; i++) {
            if (min[i])
                putchar(i);
        } //2nd_for
    }
```

Comment: you're resetting the `min` array during the loop. Is that intentional?

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre Yes, but im not sure if it is right. Im passing a characters with `getchar()` and I'm trying to loop through all of them.

Answer (score 0):

`void leastOften(int *s)` this function is looking at an integer array, you mean to look at a character array.

Note that valid ASCII range is between 0 to 128, and within that range there are many characters which never occur. For example it is unlikely you have the `^` character, it's occurrence will be zero. There will be many characters which don't occur and thus they have the lowest number. But you are probably not interested in those characters. You might want to limit the range between `'A'` to `'Z'` and `'a'` to `'z'` etc.

This function looks for characters which appear at least once, and they appear the least often:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void least(char *buf)
{
    int i;
    int len = strlen(buf);
    int counter[256];
    memset(counter, 0, sizeof(counter)); //initialize the counter

    for (i = 0; i < len; i++) //find the occurence of each letter
        counter[(unsigned char)buf[i]]++;

    int min = 0xFFFF; //assing to a large number
    for (i = 0; i < 256; i++)
        if (counter[i] && counter[i] < min)
            min = counter[i];

    printf("character(s) which appear once, and the least often:\n");
    for (i = 0; i < 256; i++)
        if (counter[i] && counter[i] == min)
            printf("%c ", (char)i);
    printf("\n");
}

int main()
{
    least("ABBCCDDEEFGG");
    return 0;
}
```